# Is there a specific component that works with Swift 3 to represent a "ComboBox / Spinner"?

Tags: ios, swift, combobox, swift3, spinner

I'm starting to work with **Swift 3** and I'm having difficult to find a "easy" solution to create a "ComboBox/Spinner".

I saw some alternatives like using PickerView and Collapse TableView, but It seems to be a solutions to make these components to looks like a ComboBox, It's a adaptation, but It's not a "real comboBox".

I would like to know If there's a component that works with Swift 3 that really represents a ComboBox/Spinner.

Thank you.

Comment: `There's a specific component in Swift 3 to represent a “ComboBox / Spinner”?` *No, because Swift is a programming language, not a framework.* That being said, there's probably what you're looking for in iOS or one of its frameworks, and you will be able to use it with Swift...

Comment: Take a look at [cocoa controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=combobox)

Comment: If you don't want to use cocoa controls. You could also create a custom button, put all those buttons in an array, show them in your view and write the logic yourself to create a combo box effect.

Comment: My idea was not use frameworks, just Swift 3.
I'll have to make It using pickerView.

Comment: @BrunoMori, did you see my answer ? I thought maybe that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric says in his comment, controls aren't defined in Swift, they're defined in the OS frameworks.

iOS does not have a combo box. That's a Windows thing. The standard system component for picking items from a list is a UIPickerView. I've implemented a custom control that's rather like a combox box before, and you may be able to find a 3rd party control that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the kind of combobox system you are looking for:

https://gyazo.com/ce6388cf29f9c33f67df2b6a54c95768

If so you could create a custom button which looks like a combobox. Then if not selected you have an image of a not selected combobox and when someone selects the button change it to the image of a selected combobox.

You create an array, add the amount of custom buttons to the array as you want, you give each button the same selector. Then when someone selects an item, deselect another button if there is one selected and select the button the user did press.

I hope this helps you.